# enum as parameter in c function

Tags: c, enums

I am writing a Library to load and save ascii and binary images. I defined an Enum containing 4 different flags for 4 different ways to save a bitmap:

```
enum jmpr_PNMMode
{
    BINARY_PPM,             /* Binary Portable Pixmap (P6)  */
    ASCII_PPM,          /* Portable pixmap ASCII (P3)   */
    BINARY_PGM,         /* Portable Graymap binary (P5) */
    ASCII_PGM            /* Portable Graymap ASCII (P2) */
};
```

I pass those to my save-function as a parameter:

```
void jmpr_savePNM(char* filename, jmpr_Image* img, enum jmpr_PNMMode mode)
{

}
```

Now how can I check which distinct instance of the enum I got? it doesn't work with:

```
if (strcmp(mode, "ASCII_PPM") != 0)
```

since the second parameter is technically not a char*.

Comment: `mode == ASCII_PPM`. Or `switch/case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code:

```
enum jmpr_PNMMode
{
    BINARY_PPM,             /* Binary Portable Pixmap (P6)  */
    ASCII_PPM,          /* Portable pixmap ASCII (P3)   */
    BINARY_PGM,         /* Portable Graymap binary (P5) */
    ASCII_PGM            /* Portable Graymap ASCII (P2) */
};
```

gives meaningful names to 4 integers, where `BINARY_PPM` is 0 and each following line increments that number by 1.

so the code in the called function could be using:

```
if ( BINARY_PPM == mode )
    ...
else if( ASCII_PPM == mode )
    ...
else if( BINARY_PGM == mode )
    ...
else if( ASCII_PGM == mode )
    ...
else
{
    perror( "invalid mode sent to jmpr_savePNM()" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

or could be using:

```
switch( mode )
    case BINARY_PPM: 
        ...
        break;

    case ASCII_PPM:
        ...
        break;

    case BINARY_PGM:
        ...
        break;

    case ASCII_PGM:
        ...
        break;

    default:
        perror( "invalid mode sent to jmpr_savePNM()" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        break;
} // end switch()
```

for clarity in the code and ease of readability and understanding, I would use the `switch()` statement.

Answer (score 4):

`strcmp` is used for strings. `enum` is actually a type of `int`, so `mode == ASCII_PPM` will be the right way of comparison

**6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers**

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants **that have type int** and may appear wherever such are permitted.

Answer (score 3):

enums are not strings, so you should not use strcmp. They are basically integers under the hood.  You need to change your if statement to...

```
if (ASCII_PPM == mode)
```

or you can use switch statement, E.g.

```
switch (mode)
{
    case ASCII_PPM:
        ProcessAsciiPpm();
        break;

    case BINARY_PPM:
        ProcessBinaryPpm();
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```